# Start over from first image when slide has reached end

Tags: javascript, jquery

When my slide through images reaches the end, it stops. I have tried to make it start over, but can't make it happend. I hope someone can help me archieve this, taking base in my code. I followed som tutorials on how to create an image slider with JQuery, so I don't want to go away from the code that I have written (If that's possible). The solutions I've found so far are written with total different ideas.
Here is the html code:

```
<body style="background-color: lightblue">
<div>
    <div id="slider" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 800px; height: 800px; margin-top: 100px;">
        <img src="./images/Dogs.jpg" style="position: absolute;" class="active" />
        <img src="./images/pic.jpg" style="position: absolute;" />          
        <img src="./images/Mal.jpg" style="position: absolute;" />

    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the JS code:

```
function startSlide() {
    var $current = $('div #slider img.active');
    var $next = $current.next();        

    if($current.length == 0) {
        $next = $('#slider  div:first-child');
        //This is what where the code will go I guess
    }

//  $next.addClass('active');   
    $current.removeClass('active').css({
        "opacity" : 0.0,
        "zIndex" : 2
        });
        $("#slider img").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 2000, function() {
            $next.addClass('active').css({zIndex: 1});
        });
}
```

So my question is how to write the code so that the slide will start over once it reaches the last image. And preferably keeping the JQuery syntax
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle out and see if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/eNuwv/2/

I modified the assignment for `$next` when the length of `$current` is zero to look like this:

`$next = $('#slider :first-child');`

and I changed the `animate` block at the end to use the reference to `$next` instead of the selector you had.

```
$next.animate({opacity: 1.0}, 2000, function() {
    $next.addClass('active').css({zIndex: 1});
});
```

Hope that helps.

ps. I'm not sure how you intend for the entire thing to initialize so the fiddle starts with all 3 images visible -- clicking the Start Slide link a few times will get you to a state where you should be able to cycle through.

I didn't have your CSS for class `.active` but maybe you are using it simply as a marker.

Comment: Hi. The .active doesn't have any css so far

Answer (score 1):

This is the complete code that works for me, you would have to play with the timings a little bit probably:

I used David's tip.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){startSlide()}, 2100);
});

function startSlide() {
    var $current = $('div #slider img.active');
    var $next = $current.next();        

    if($next.length == 0) {
        $next = $('#slider :first-child');
    //make sure you don't make an empty circle
}
$current.removeClass('active');
$current.css({
    "opacity" : "0.0",
    "zIndex" : "2"
});
$next.animate({opacity: 1.0}, 2000, function() {
    $next.addClass('active').css({zIndex: 1});
});
```

}

I also added opacity:0 to the images that you don't want to display in the beginning.

Comment: The above code works regarding rotating from start, once reaching the last image. However, when I start the slide show, it first starts of with the last image, staying there for like 3 seconds, swicts to the image that lies 2nd in the queue staying there for 1 second, back to the last image again, for 1 second, and THEN it starts working normally. And I can't debug it for some reason. It just steps out when I click F11 (to step into). Any idea why? And thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Did you use my pure solution, or was there something else added to it by your side? Not sure why it doesn't allow you to step into it.

Comment: I used your pure solution. But I have it working now. I split up the part in the animate() code, to be like this:
next.addClass('active');
next.animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 2500);  
Then it worked for some reason. And thanks a lot for the help